# Kill a process that runs under valgrind and create summary

Tags: valgrind, suse

I use the valgrind version 3.12.0 under x86_64 GNU/Linux. The distibuition of Linux is the Suse version 3.0.101-63-default.
I try to terminate the valgrind process using kill pid , but the signal is ignored.
Only when the SIGBUS signal is sent the valgrind is terminated and the summary is created.
But I do not know if using this signal I take the correct results?
Is any other way to terminate the valgrind?
I use kill -9 but no summary is create at all

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321398/terminate-process-running-inside-valgrind
kill -SIGTERM <pid> // or SIGUSR1/SIGUSR2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, kill -9 does not allow valgrind to produce a report, as signal 9
cannot be handled by a process.
Any other signal that will terminate your program will be properly handled
by Valgrind, and lead to e.g. a correct leak report for memcheck tool.

Note that by using from a shell the vgdb command, you can give instructions
to valgrind during execution. For example, you can trigger a leak search.

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.valgrind-monitor-commands for more information.

Comment: I have been trying to get sigint to a program under valgrind and no matter what I do, I can't get valgrind to forward it on. This is on OS X.

Comment: @jtgrassie I am not using OSX so cannot help much. Try to run with -v -v -v -d -d -d --trace-signals=yes, that might give a hint about the problem.